# como mostrar dos divs cada vez que presione los botones de siguiente y anterior con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lo que necesito es hacer una especie de paginado pero solo con botones de atrás y adelante y que me muestre solo de a dos divs, tengo el siguiente código, pero este solo muestra de a un solo div a la vez:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".divs div.panel").each(function(e) {
          if (e != 0)
              $(this).hide();
    
      } );
    
      $("#next").click(function(){
          if ($(".divs div.panel:visible").next().length != 0)
              $(".divs div.panel:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
          else {
              // $(".divs div.panel:visible").hide();
              // $(".divs div.panel:first").show();
          }
          return false;
      });
    
      $("#prev").click(function(){
          if ($(".divs div.panel:visible").prev().length != 0)
              $(".divs div.panel:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
          else {
    
              // $(".divs div.panel:visible").hide();
              // $(".divs div.panel:last").show();
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
        <div class="panel">1</div>
        <div class="panel">2</div>
        <div class="panel">3</div>
        <div class="panel">4</div>
        <div class="panel">5</div>
        <div class="panel">6</div>
        <div class="panel">7</div>
    </div>
    <a id="prev">prev</a>
    <a id="next">next</a>
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a que mostrara de a dos divs cada vez sería genial!

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una variable para almacenar la posición actual y, en función de esta, ir calculando los divs a mostrar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 0;
  var $divs = $(".divs div.panel");
  
  function show(index){
    current = index;
    var next = $divs.length <= current + 1 ? 0 : current + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < $divs.length; i++){
      (i === current || i === next)
        ? $($divs[i]).show()
        : $($divs[i]).hide();
    }
  }

  $("#next").click(function() {
    next = current + 2;
    if ($divs.length <= next){
      next = next - $divs.length;
    }
    show(next);
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    prev = current -2;
    if (prev < 0){
      prev = $divs.length + prev;      
    }
    show(prev);
    return false;
  });
  
  show(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="panel">1</div>
  <div class="panel">2</div>
  <div class="panel">3</div>
  <div class="panel">4</div>
  <div class="panel">5</div>
  <div class="panel">6</div>
  <div class="panel">7</div>
</div>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a>
```